# retrieve content from blogger post to display on Home page using specific labels posts

Tags: javascript, json, blogger

I am displaying posts from a specific label on the home page.

Then, in it,  I have to display some more information for each particular posts of that label. As shown in the image below -

[image: Label]

I am not an expert but I think we can do it with JavaScript. by applying reference codes or variables in while writing each post such as:-

**var/code**  *some texts to retrieve from this post to home page under label posts* **var/code**]

and retrieve it using javascript to display  on specific label posts on the home page

still didn't find any clue how can I do this.. any suggestion, please.

this is code to show specific lable post on home page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function labelthumbs(json) {
    document.write('<ul id="label_with_thumbs">');
    for(var i = 0; i < numposts; i++) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
        var posturl;
        if(i == json.feed.entry.length) break;
        for(var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
            if(entry.link[k].rel == 'replies' && entry.link[k].type == 'text/html') {
                var commenttext = entry.link[k].title;
                var commenturl = entry.link[k].href;
            }
            if(entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                posturl = entry.link[k].href;
                break;
            }
        }
        var thumburl;
        try {
            thumburl = entry.media$thumbnail.url;
        } catch(error) {
            s = entry.content.$t;
            a = s.indexOf("<img");
            b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);
            c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);
            d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
            if((a != -1) && (b != -1) && (c != -1) && (d != "")) {
                thumburl = d;
            } else thumburl = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-zP87C2q9yog/UVopoHY30SI/AAAAAAAAE5k/AIyPvrpGLn8/s1600/picture_not_available.png';
        }
        var postdate = entry.published.$t;
        var cdyear = postdate.substring(0, 4);
        var cdmonth = postdate.substring(5, 7);
        var cdday = postdate.substring(8, 10);
        var monthnames = new Array();
        monthnames[1] = "Jan";
        monthnames[2] = "Feb";
        monthnames[3] = "Mar";
        monthnames[4] = "Apr";
        monthnames[5] = "May";
        monthnames[6] = "June";
        monthnames[7] = "July";
        monthnames[8] = "Aug";
        monthnames[9] = "Sept";
        monthnames[10] = "Oct";
        monthnames[11] = "Nov";
        monthnames[12] = "Dec";
        document.write('<li class="clearfix">');
        if(showpostthumbnails == true) document.write('<a href="' + posturl + '" target ="_top"><img class="label_thumb" src="' + thumburl + '"/></a>');
        document.write('<strong><a href="' + posturl + '" target ="_top">' + posttitle + '</a></strong><br>');
        if("content" in entry) {
            var postcontent = entry.content.$t;
        }
        elseif("summary" in entry) {
            var postcontent = entry.summary.$t;
        } else var postcontent = "";
        var re = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
        postcontent = postcontent.replace(re, "");
        if(showpostsummary == true) {
            if(postcontent.length < numchars) {
                document.write('');
                document.write(postcontent);
                document.write('');
            } else {
                document.write('');
                postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, numchars);
                var quoteEnd = postcontent.lastIndexOf(" ");
                postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, quoteEnd);
                document.write(postcontent + '...');
                document.write('');
            }
        }
        var towrite = '';
        var flag = 0;
        document.write('<br>');
        if(showpostdate == true) {
            towrite = towrite + monthnames[parseInt(cdmonth, 10)] + '-' + cdday + ' - ' + cdyear;
            flag = 1;
        }
        if(showcommentnum == true) {
            if(flag == 1) {
                towrite = towrite + ' | ';
            }
            if(commenttext == '1 Comments') commenttext = '1 Comment';
            if(commenttext == '0 Comments') commenttext = 'No Comments';
            commenttext = '<a href="' + commenturl + '" target ="_top">' + commenttext + '</a>';
            towrite = towrite + commenttext;
            flag = 1;;
        }
        if(displaymore == true) {
            if(flag == 1) towrite = towrite + ' | ';
            towrite = towrite + '<a href="' + posturl + '" class="url" target ="_top">More »</a>';
            flag = 1;;
        }
        document.write(towrite);
        document.write('</li>');
        if(displayseparator == true)
            if(i != (numposts - 1)) document.write('');
    }
    document.write('</ul>');
}
//]]>
</script>
```

display codes:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var numposts = 3;
var showpostthumbnails = true;
var displaymore = false;
var displayseparator = true;
var showcommentnum = false;
var showpostdate = false;
var showpostsummary = true;
var numchars = 100;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/default/-/label name?published&alt=json-in-script&callback=labelthumbs"></script>
```